# What is this unusual leading edge flap on a B737-200?

Tags: aircraft-design, boeing-737, flaps, feature-identification

On [this video](https://youtu.be/mFytkKjvpqg) of Air North's gravel runway-equipped B737-200, there's what appears to be a small leading-edge flap (Krueger flap?) inboard of the engine.  Refer to the screen shot below.  What is this?

[image]

### Addendum

Notice in the video (and screen shot) that this device shows itself while no other flaps are extended.

Comment: Hard to say. Looks more like an access panel hanging down during servicing than a Kruger flap, which will be hinged at the front of the LE.

Comment: A closer view of a [similar LE flap](http://www.flickriver.com/photos/francoisroche/2592515014/). I don't understand why the first answer by @TomMcW was downvoted, it seems to be the good one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are two leading edge Krueger flap surfaces at each side of the wing, you can see details about them according IPC and AMM documents I found over the internet:

[image: LE Kruger slat]

[image: LE Kruger slat Mechanism]

[image: LE Kruger slat Section]

Regarding the Addendum, and why it seems that there is no other flaps deployed, I found a similar topic at [Airliner.net Forum](https://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=773107). As it is mentioned there, when is no hydraulic pressure, they can be extended by their weight:

> ...it has to do with the shut off valves and the actuators relaxing with no hydraulic pressure on them.

and also:

> ...Pressurize the system and they all move to their present commanded position

and another sidenote:

> ...Someone pulled that Krueger Flap to the fully extended position. When they droop because of no pressure on the system there in the mid positions.

and as final note, this issue is also mentioned in the AMM:

[image: LE Flap Droop issue in the AMM]

Comment: We have removed the images in your answer due to a DMCA complaint from Boeing. I realize this breaks your answer a lot. Please consider updating it in a way that makes it useful again without using copyrighted images.

Comment: @animuson thanks for updating me. I found those documents on the internet. Now, I even can't see what images I had posted, and unfortunately, I don't remember them, to repost similar images.

Answer (score -1):

The 737-200 does have Krueger flaps inboard of the engines as seen in this photo

[image]
<sup>[source](http://www.b737.org.uk/737original.htm#737-100)</sup>

It’s hard to really tell, but it looks like the outboard half of the flap is not entirely retracted.

Comment: Curious, where did you get that image? Is there a higher-res version available online?

Comment: Oh shoot! Did I forget to put a citation? I think it was on the site B737.com. I'll see if it's still in my browser history

Comment: @pr1268 There. I added a citation link